# App crashes when re-opening. WP 8.1

Tags: c#, crash, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have developed an app for Windows Phone and put it into my phone.
When I launch this app after it has been already opened and is among the background tasks, it crashes for no reason.

I tried to recreate the problem on debug mode, wiring the phone to my computer and testing within Visual Studio to see if there was any exception error:
I launched the app, 
I pressed the home button (the app is now in the background, you can see it pressing left arrow button), 
I re-opened the app tapping on its icon, and it worked perfectly.

The problem is, when I do it without Visual Studio, just using it as a normal app, it crashes when re-opening. And again, I don't think this is caused by an exception throw, because in debug mode, I have no exception throw whatsoever.

Did you guys ever ran into this ?

Comment: there has to be a reason.. perhaps there is something wrong with your code.. and sometimes in debug mode the compiler tends to suppress certain things.. perhaps you have the infamous `Object not set to an Instance` error .. when it crashes why not put some logging functionality to return call stack etc.. have it write to a file or something.. also can you show the code perhaps you are not Disposing of objects correctly.. if you are creating and or using `List<Class>` object somewhere perhaps you are not `newing` the objects correctly..

Comment: also how do you expect anyone to help you when you have visual access to viewing the code.. we do not.. ??

Comment: I don't think I'm gonna post the code because it is massive (500 lines). I will check for the things that you said because I am indeed using a List. Also I don't understand why the `Object not set to an Instance` would show up ONLY when I am RE-OPENING the app and not when I am launching it.

Comment: there is an easy way for you to check this do a full search and select entire solution and search on the text `= new` and see if you are initializing properly and or freeing objects also where you declare an Instance of an object for example if you are using a List<string>  object above any actual code blocks for example `List<string> myList;` before using and or populating `myList` you need to create the actual instance by doing something like this `myList =  new List<string>` hope this help in regards to you tracking down the error.

Answer (score 0):

First, I must say that there **is** exception that crash your app. In debug mode you **cant** catch it so far because the app **never** go to suspended state (the debuger keeps it active), so there is no re-launch event happend.

My suggestion: check the code in **OnLaunch** method in **App.xaml.cs**. Relaunch app will run those code again, there is hight chance that you are not guared again that.

Second, debug the OnResuming event happend when you return from suspended state. You can do it in debug mode, read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974425.aspx).

Hope you find it helpful and get your problem solved :)

Comment: Thank you, I will try it as soon as I can.